# Theoretical justification for Cochran's rule in the $\chi^2$ test

Tags: statistics

There is an empirical rule performing a $\chi^2$ test for goodness of fit: the expected frequencies have all to be greater then or equal to 5. Does someone knows why? Is there any proof?